# for loop in multidimensional array on a selector for car shop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a selector for a car shop of make, model and year.

it no work fine... i only can select ALFA ROMEO and AUDI cars.

I think the problem is on my for inner loop.

```
$.each(carJson.marca, function (index, value) {
$("#marca").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
```

});

$('#marca').on('change', function () {
console.log($(this).val() ); // Marca.Id

```
for (var i = 0; i < carJson.marca.length; i++) {
    if (carJson.marca[i].id == $(this).val()) {
        $('#model').html('<option value="000">-Model-</option>');
        $.each(carJson.marca[i].model, function (index, value) {
        $("#model").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');                  
        });    

}    

$('#model').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).val() );
    for (var b=0; b < carJson.marca.length ; b++)    {     
        for ( var c=0; c < 2 ; c++) {

        //for ( var c=0; c < carJson.marca[b].model.length ; c++) {
            if(carJson.marca[b].model[c].id == $(this).val()){
         $('#eng').html('<option value="000">-Motorsss!-</option>');
         $.each(carJson.marca[b].model[c].engine, function (index, value) {
         $("#eng").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');

        });              
      }
    }
}
```

} );

```
}
```

});

I Attached the code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LeqTn/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me with your fiddle? (Chrome)

Comment: Try to choose the first time any BMW car. Only works Serie1 and Serie3, no?

Comment: it works for all of them, mostly

Comment: maybe I have explained badly.
What is not working is when selecting the year, i can't select the year of FIAT>PANDA>?